# How to load WASM in Expo (react-native) App

Tags: react-native, expo, webassembly, react-native-hermes

How can I load a wasm file into an expo react native app? I am using `"expo": "~49.0.8"`

Here is everything I have tried:
I tried using `Asset` and `useAssets` from `expo-assets`

I tried loading it with `fetch` from `fetch('../assets/my-wasm-file.wasm')`.

I also tried simply importing it like: `import wasm from "my-node-module-package-that-has-a-wasm-file/path/to/wasm-file.wasm"` and that didn't work either.

The last thing I tried was this packages `https://github.com/cawfree/react-native-webassembly`.
I tried the `import HelloWorld from './hello-world.wasm';` method mentioned than the `axios` method. The axios method seemed to get me closer to the target but I got an error saying there was an issue with `hermes`. I tried to disable hermes in `ios/Podfile` and then run `pod install` but it didn't work.